# kubernetes - k3d how to use local directory as a Persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, k3d

I am using k3d to run local kubernetes

I have created a cluster using k3d.

Now I want to mount a local directory as a persistent volume.

How can i do this while using k3d.

I know in minikube

```
$ minikube start --mount-string="$HOME/go/src/github.com/nginx:/data" --mount
```

Then If you mount /data into your Pod using `hostPath`, you will get you local directory data into Pod.

Is there any similar technique here also while using k3d

Comment: Did you see [this example](https://dev.to/bbende/k3s-on-raspberry-pi-volumes-and-storage-1om5#:~:text=K3s%20comes%20with%20a%20default,where%20the%20pod%20is%20located.) how volumes and storage work in a K3s cluster?

Comment: Were you able to do it? I'm looking for a way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answers to [this Github question](https://github.com/k3d-io/k3d/issues/566) the feature you're looking for is not available yet.

Here is some idea from this link:

> The simplest I guess would be to have a pretty generic mount containing all the code, e.g. in my case, I could do `k3d cluster create -v "$HOME/git:/git@agent:*"` to get all the repositories on my host present in all agent nodes to be used for hot-reloading.

According to [this](https://k3d.io/v5.2.0/usage/commands/k3d_cluster_create/) documentation one can use the following command with the adequate flag:

```yaml
k3d cluster create NAME -v [SOURCE:]DEST[@NODEFILTER[;NODEFILTER...]]
```

This command mounts volumes into the nodes

```
(Format:[SOURCE:]DEST[@NODEFILTER[;NODEFILTER...]]
```

Example:

```
`k3d cluster create --agents 2 -v /my/path@agent:0,1 -v /tmp/test:/tmp/other@server:0`
```

[Here](https://dev.to/bbende/k3s-on-raspberry-pi-volumes-and-storage-1om5) is also an interesting article how volumes and storage work in a K3s cluster (with examples).

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature is not yet available
https://github.com/k3d-io/k3d/issues/566

So far we can only mount volumn when we create a new cluster.

```
k3d cluster create mykube --volume HOME/go/src/github.com/nginx:/data
```